# How do I display the content in the second column of this array onchange using javascript only

Tags: javascript, html

I asked a question earlier today and was able to get someone to shed light on what my problem was so I am hoping that lightning would strike twice.

I am trying to display information from the second column when you select the information on the dropdown.

For example I want to be able to select "Text A1" and the text that would be displayed is "Text A2". Here is what I have so far.

**My script in the head section**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var maps = new Array();
        maps[0] = "Select one";
        maps[1] = "Text A1", "Text A2", "Text A3";
        maps[2] = "Text B1", "Text B2", "Text B3";
        maps[3] = "Text C1", "Text C2", "Text C3";
        maps[4] = "Text D1", "Text D2", "Text D3";
        maps[5] = "Text E1", "Text E2", "Text E3";
        maps[6] = "Text F1", "Text F2", "Text F3";
    var map = document.getElementById("complaintType");
    for (i=0;i<maps.length;i++) {
        var Entry = document.createElement("option");
        Entry.text = maps[i];
        map.add(Entry ,null);
    }
    function showhide() {
        var div = document.getElementById("complaintMap");
        if (div.style.display !== "none") {
            div.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    var list = document.getElementById('complaintType');
    var tag = document.getElementById('tag');
    list.onchange = function() {
    tag.innerHTML = this.value;
  }
}
</script>
```

**My HTML**

```
<form>
    <select name="complaintType" id="complaintType">
    </select>
</form>

<div id="tag"></div>
```

My hunch is that I need to change line 30 from saying

```
tag.innerHTML = this.value;
```

to say

```
tag.innerHTML = XXXX.value;
```

Problem is, I dont know what to change the XXXX to. 
Am I barking up the wrong tree or am I on the right path?
And I am  only able to do it in javascript. No love for JQuery

Comment: You want what you think is values in the array, but the commas in that context is just wrong, however it's not invalid, but the "columns" you're trying to add to the array is never added.

Comment: sorta, but you went the wrong way :) what you did was go one down, so selecting A1 would display B1. What I need help with, is selecting A1 would dislplay A2. Thanks again

Comment: I didn't get it at first, but you see, `maps[1] = "Text A1", "Text A2", "Text A3";` is not doing what you think, the only thing that is added to the array is `Text A1`, whatever comes after the comma is not added at all, you probably wanted `maps[1] = ["Text A1", "Text A2", "Text A3"];`, but then you'd have to make some changes to other things as well.

Comment: ooooo. crap, I hope I dont have to write this thing all over again.

Comment: Not really, just make some changes, here's one way to do it -> **http://jsfiddle.net/j2cyuk0v/**

Comment: Dam it, you where faster @adeneo, still I wonder, why not just use one array with objects in it, since json_encode in most laguage will encode an array correctly.

Comment: Im loosing my mind. I tried to take it out of JS Fiddle and there is a greater/less sign and because of that I cant close the script tag. Dont get me wrong it works PERFECTLY in JS Fiddle

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion your `maps` array isn't proper Javascript. When I test it in Firefox, I get one array like

```
0 => 'Select one',
1 => 'Text A1',
2 => 'Text B1',
...
```

I guess your are trying to get something like

```
var maps = new Array();
maps.push(new Array('Text A1', 'Text A2', 'Text A3'));
maps.push(new Array('Text B1', 'Text B2', 'Text B3'));
...
```

Since I guess you read those texts/values from a database, just use `JSON encode` (for PHP for example `<?php echo json_encode(array(array('Text A1', 'Text A2'), array('Text B1', 'Text B2'))); ?>`, you get the idea.

This just to the arrays. For your particular problem:

I made a little fiddle that does what you want. It doesn't only use arrays but also objects. Take a look and ask if you don't understand how it works: http://jsfiddle.net/rdfg3dch/

Btw. PHP for the maps stuff would be something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var maps = <?php echo json_encode(array(
        array('option' => 'Text', 'text' => 'Text'),
        array('option' => 'displayed', 'text' => 'displayed'),
        array('option' => 'in', 'text' => 'in'),
        array('option' => 'Dropdown', 'text' => 'Output'),
        array('option' => 'Foo', 'text' => 'Bar')
    )); ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: Yayy thanks for the downvote, would you mind to explain why, the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/rdfg3dch/ that I provide should work as expected, doesn't it?

Comment: OH NOO Im sorry I had no idea that I did that AND I cant remove it. I swear I didnt do it on purpose and I need 15 rep to raise it.